# Maintenance of parking sensors

Tags: ford, sensor, parking

I have issues with the parking sensors on my wife's S-max (2007). The sensors would occasionally beep (constant beep) after turning on the car and selecting a gear. I tried cleaning them, but I noticed that the paint is pealing away in the process. After removing the paint the beeping seems to improve, but the sensors started looking quite bad (they are in some metalic colour). How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the sensors were detecting the loose paint as an object very close. You should be able to re-paint them, but I don't know if they would need a special sort of paint - it might be worth checking with Ford